# Не работает $APPLICATION->AddHeadScript() в файле component_epilog.php шаблона компонента

Tags: php, битрикс

Настраиваю ссылку "Поделиться в Facebook", а именно - название новости с помощью внедрения в шапку header.php шаблона сайта тега meta.

Вот весь код component_epilog.php:

> if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
>
> global $APPLICATION;
>
> $APPLICATION->AddHeadString('meta property="og:title" content="'.$arResult["NAME"].'" ');

символы < > и < ? ? >   пропущены

В шапке header.php шаблона сайта есть строка

> $APPLICATION->ShowHead();

Если я прописываю напрямую в header.php шаблона сайта внедряемую строку, то всё работает, а мне надо, чтобы из component_epilog.php было. А так не получается(  Что я упустил?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно, что у вас не работает, в заголовке у вас указана функция AddHeadScript, а в коде AddHeadString, может вы используете именно AddHeadScript, поэтому и не работает? Или может кавычки какие-то есть в $arResult["NAME"], лучше использовать там htmlspecialchars.

А еще можно сделать как [вот здесь](http://g-rain-design.ru/blog/posts/facebook-right-posting-how-to/) описано:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?=$APPLICATION->ShowTitle("title",true)?>" />
```

Или использовать отложенные функции, т.е. в вашем component_epilog.php устанавливать свойство страницы:

```
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("OG_TITLE",$arResult["NAME"]);
```

А в хедере выводить:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?=$APPLICATION->ShowProperty("OG_TITLE")?>" />
```

Также еще есть вариант, что ваш $arResult["NAME"] находиться в component_epilog.php только при сбросе кеша, проверьте этот момент.